# Can we set up a Documentation section right like in stack overflow?

Tags: support, documentation

I read today about the new Documentation section in stackoverflow and I think we really can benefit from that.

I don't see the option to create such a thing, but maybe a moderator with more reputation actually could (but maybe that's not an option right now, since the stack overflow Documentation section is a beta).

So... In the event we cannot create a Documentation section right now, should we as a community start creating documentation about ethereum in the stack overflow page? (there are some questions 'bout ethereum there too) And maybe later replicate that docs here? Or should we wait 'til we have our own Documentation section?

Answer (score 5):

No, the documentation is Stackoverflow-only. However, we could try to set up documentation over there for [solidity](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/solidity) or [ethereum](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/ethereum) tags.

This again, does not work (yet), because the tags are not active enough.

> This tag is too new, or too low activity, for Documentation to be created for it.

There is an [ongoing discussion on the criteria on meta stackoverflow](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/328419/1260906) if you wish to follow that more closely. We might be able to do that some day in the future.